# Django threadedcomments - registered users

Tags: django-comments

I am planning to use Django's comment system (with the threadedcomments app).
Since I only allow registered users to post, the mandatory user/url/email fields are not needed (just want a ForeignKey(User)).

I have a feeling I am not the first (nor the 1000th) to do this, can anyone point me to any implementations ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need.
http://api.rst2a.com/1.0/rst2/html?uri=http%3A//django-threadedcomments.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api.txt&style=zope

> **FreeThreadedComment**
> FreeThreadedComment  is better suited for allowing just about anyone to post comments on an item. Instead of being associated with a particular user, instead it asks for some additional information like name and e-mail.
>
> **ThreadedComment**
> ThreadedComment  is useful for allowing registered users to comment. It is for this reason that there is a required foreign key to User.